# Find the tangent space of Ellipsoid $M = \{(x,y,z)|\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1\}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, tangent-spaces

> Find the tangent space of 
>   $$M = \{(x,y,z)|\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1\}$$

So I know the formula of tangent space for a manifold represnted by $F$ such that $F=0$: it is $ker (DF)$.

So I'll define - $F = \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2} - 1$ and of course $F=0$.

By definition, $DF = (\frac{2x}{a^2},\frac{2y}{b^2},\frac{2z}{c^2})$ and we just need to find $ker (DF)$.

Besides $x=y=z=0$, the solutions are $(x,y,(-\frac{x^2}{a^2} -\frac{y^2}{b^2} )c^2)$, $(x,(-\frac{x^2}{a^2} -\frac{z^2}{c^2})b^2,z)$ and $(-\frac{y^2}{b^2} -\frac{z^2}{c^2} )a^2,y,z)$.

But what is the final tangent space that is spanned by these solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a point $p \in M$, the tangent space to $M$ is given by $ker(DF(p))$, as you said. So, in your case, it is the set of points $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}$ such that (I divided the $2$ which comes from differentiating)

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
    \dfrac{p_1}{a^2} & \dfrac{p_2}{b^2} & \dfrac{p_3}{c^2}
\end{pmatrix} 
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
    x \\
    y \\
    z
\end{pmatrix}
&= 0 \\
\dfrac{p_1}{a^2}x + \dfrac{p_2}{b^2}y + \dfrac{p_3}{c^2}z &= 0
\end{align*}

In other words the tangent space of $M$ at $p$ is the plane through the origin given by the equation above.

(If you want the actual tangent plane to $M$ at the point $p$, you simply have to translate the plane to pass through $p$, by replacing $(x,y,z)$ with $(x-p_1, y-p_2, z-p_3)$)